# Printing an array from another function in C

Tags: c, function

I have some problems understanding how to do this kind of stuffs. I have already made a function that does the logical part like declaring an Integer that get the value of the array[i] and this number is random picked from the array(i think). Anyway here is the code that I have done:

```
void array_test( int arr[]  , int size)
{
    int i;
    int random_number;

    for(i = 0; i<size; i++){
         random_number = (rand() %15 + 1);
         arr[i] = random_number;
    }

}
```

Now my question is how do I print the result(the code works and it does print out 15 different numbers between 1 and 15. I have defined the size to 15 and it is on the function prototype parameter) using another function? The function takes a `char output[]` as one parameter, 
an array of type `int`, and a size of type `int`. 
Looks like this `output_result(char output[], int arr[], int size)`.

The thing is that I don't understand how I'm supposed to call the stuff from the previous function to this and then show it to the user. I admit that this is an assignment but I have tried many things and nothing works. The thing is that I have to printf all the arrays(?) value by using a for-loop. It's here it just get messy. I've tried to create the wheel again ,so to say, by copy pasting the code from the function array_test but then the function array_test would be unnecessary to implement. No pointers shall be used until next assignment.

Here is the main function:

```
int main() {
  int arr[SIZE]; 

  srand(time(0)); 
  array_test(arr, SIZE);
  print_array("This is an array\0", arr, SIZE);

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Well, you must have a "main" function where you allocate the array, no?  Then, in main(), after you call array_test(), just add another "for" loop to printf each element.

Comment: can you show the printing function and the `main` function? what is th expected output an the output/errors you get?

Comment: What is the `output` parameter of the `output_result()` function supposed to be?  A tag identifying what is being printed?  Or the name of a file?  It could be either.  Is `print_values_ver1()` related to `output_result()`?  You do not need the explicit `\0` in the string; the C compiler automatically adds a null byte for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print the entire array, you can do the following:

**EDIT**: Based on your main function that you gave us, your `print_values_ver1` function could look something like this:

In your main function, to find array size you would use this:

`int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);`

Then pass that you your print function like:

`print_values_ver1("Some text\0", arr, size);`

and your function definition would look something like:

```
print_values_ver1(char[] output, int arr[], int SIZE) {

    for (int z = 0; z < SIZE; z ++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that `%d` is a format specifier of the `printf` function (see [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)). And `\n` is a `newline` character.

This code iterates through each element of the array and prints the value (one value per line).

Comment: What is this `arr.length` thing?

Comment: You can use that only if you're in the main method where the array is declared.

Comment: need to use the original array for `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);` in main.  sizeof does not work with pointers, therefore cannot use it in called function that way.  Get it, then pass the value.

Comment: regarding your statement - `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])` which is the equivalent of `length.` Wrong, it is not. .length is c#, it handles pointers, the sizeof version (C) does not.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing that but it was ambiguous because we didn't know how he was passing the array around in main. I was assuming that he was getting size in main (which is if you look now), and passing it to his print function. In the context of `main`, it does work.

Comment: No, but we can see that he is passing an `int size` argument, so I assumed he had that figured out. :)  Your code looks fine now. +1

Comment: Well if he didn't, because it seems like he's new to C, he can use that statement to find the actual length of his array, then pass that number to his print function.

Comment: Yeah about sizeof, I have already defined it. I can thank @ChrisCirefice for his anticipation because I am one step closer finishing the program :D  This question is now solved and I hope it'll help other people around the world

Comment: Good, I'm glad! My first experience with C was miserable, it took me about two hours to figure out how to pass arrays around to other functions, find the size, etc. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you @ChrisCirefice. Yeah it's not so easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:  (comments in-line explain whys-)

[EDIT] adds `output_results()`

```
#include <ansi_c.h>

void array_test( int arr[]  , int size);
void output_result(int a[], int size);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[15]; 
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    array_test(arr, size);
    output_result(arr, size); 
    getchar();
    return 0;   
}

void output_result(int a[], int size)
{
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) printf("a[%d] is:%d\n", i, a[i]);
}

void array_test( int arr[]  , int size)
{
    int i;
    int randomly_picked_number;


    for(i = 0; i<size; i++){
         randomly_picked_number = (rand() %15 + 1);
             arr[i] = randomly_picked_number;



    }

}
```

Comment: Some hacker came by and mutilated your answer... you hacked yourself! Good you fixed it. Also, I upvoted your answer because you gave a real full-execution explanation ;)